# Ensure www using webconfig rewrite

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, umbraco

I'm working with an Umbraco asp.net website and I would like to ensure website url is alwayes displayed with www I have added:

```
    <rule name="WWW rule" stopProcessing="false">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://(?!www)(.*)" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
          </rule>
```

To me this is a good methode for making sure only one URL on website. Only issue as I see is that when typing DOMAINE only my default.aspx will be added to frontpage. 
How to avoid that?

I have tried to add:

```
<rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)default.aspx" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

This makes frontpage inside a loop.... 
Have I misunderstood somthing? Thanks

Comment: Try googling, dude. Or just our.umbraco.org. https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/73194-redirect-non-www-urls-to-www-urls (EDIT: sorry, I didn't catch the /default.aspx issue - that sounds very strange, not sure if the link solves that :-/ )

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't stopProcessing="true" for the domain rewrite? I'm guessing you don't want the rest of the rules evaluated?

Also, I'm guessing you might want to use {HTTP_HOST} in you condition, since I would guess that the {CACHE_URL} would be the one including the default.aspx path?

Currently you are using the incoming http/https schema, which are also considered different url's, so you may want to choose which one to use, or implement a canonical meta tag on your site to tell search engines which schema to use.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Changed {CACHE_URL} to {HTTP_HOST}. Now the rule is not working any more. I have tried to set stopProcessing="false"  also without any luck..

Comment: You need to adapt your rule of course, Check points 3 and 4 in this post to see what I mean: http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/#canonical

Comment: I hope you will show me example on how its done? Thanks